# How to parse CSV with node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, pandas

I'm trying to follow an example of a streamgraphs in highcharts, [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/streamgraph), but it says "parsed with node.js" instead of giving out the file/explaining how to do it.

I need to go from a csv formatted like this:

```
Category, Finland, Austria
1,        53,      29
2,        77,      88
```

To this in my js file:

```
series: [{
    name: "Finland",
    data: [
      53, 77
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Austria",
    data: [
      29, 88
    ]
  },
```

EDIT: but how do I actually merge it with the javascript script in highcharts ([here](https://highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/demo/streamgraph?codepen))?

Comment: Check this module maibe. https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: Thak you, but I don't really know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')
let csv = readFileSync('path/to/your/file.csv', 'utf-8')
const series = []
csv = csv.split('\n')
let headers = csv.shift().split(',')
headers.shift()
for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  const data = []
  for (let j = 0; j < csv.length; j++)
    data.push(csv[j].split(',')[i + 1].trim())
  csv[i].split(',')
  series.push({
    name: headers[i].trim(),
    data
  })
}
console.log(series)
```

Comment: Thank you, but exactly how do I insert it in the js file that I found here: highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/demo/streamgraph?codepen ?